# Clearing Resources on Mobile App that Plays YouTube Videos

Tags: mobile, web-applications, cordova, youtube, nodes

I have a single page mobile web app running through PhoneGap - so it's running HTML5, CSS3, JQuery.  The app provides users the ability to view a different video on each virtual page.  The videos are seen through an iframe which adds quite a burden to the application, most of all because I'm having difficulty cleaning up the iframes and their associated docs, dom nodes, and listeners.

**I'm looking for advice on how to better clean up the content associated with the YouTube iframe after the user is finished watching the video.**  This is especially important as I will be submitting the app to the the App store and I understand that poor memory and DOM management can be a killer.

YouTube is embedded with the following code:

```
<iframe id="youtube_iframe" width="300" height="200" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/clip_id?autoplay=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And the Memory Timeline from Chrome's Dev Tools looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Can we see how you are clearing the iframe? If you delete the entire iframe using jQuery's `$('iframe').remove()`, it should instantly free up memory. You can then create a fresh iframe when a new page is loaded.

Comment: yeah, I'm using `$('#youtube_iframe').attr("src", " ");` followed by `$('#youtube_iframe').remove();`  However I notice that the document count continues to rise and there are 7 listeners that I can not remove.  Is there a way to deal with this / should I not worry about it?

Comment: Ah good point, am not sure whether `.remove()` will also unbind the event listeners. It is recommended to remove them as well, however you may need to manually do it using `.off()`, for example `$('button').off('click mouseover mouseout');`

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure I can hunt those down.  And is there a way to kill off all those extra docs?  The red line keeps climbing bc I'm loading new iframes. I'd like to keep that under control. Unless it's just aesthetic, in which case i don't care.